# Google calendar style with see more button

Tags: javascript, html, css, thymeleaf

How to manage events in calendar for each day in google calendar style?

I created a calendar style and each day can have events, now I want to add some limit so each day can have at most 2 events, if there is more add see more button and after user click on it display remaining events.

This is thymeleaf so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Doctor Appointments</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/all-doctors-appointments.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="header-center">
    <h2 th:text="${monthYear}"></h2>
    <div class="button-container">
        <a class="btn btn-previous"
           th:href="@{/doctorAppointments/doctor-appointment-calendar(year=__${previousYear}__, month=__${previousMonth}__)}">Previous
            Month</a>
        <a class="btn btn-next"
           th:href="@{/doctorAppointments/doctor-appointment-calendar(year=__${nextYear}__, month=__${nextMonth}__)}">Next
            Month</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="calendar-header">
        <div th:each="dayName : ${dayNames}">
            <div th:text="${dayName}"></div>
        </div>
        <div th:each="week : ${calendarDays}" th:with="weekDates=${week}">
            <div th:each="day : ${weekDates}" class="calendar-day">
                <div class="day-number" th:text="${day.getDayOfMonth()}"></div>
                <div th:each="entry : ${doctorAppointmentsMap}"
                     th:with="doctor=${entry.key}, appointments=${entry.value}">
                    <div th:each="appointment : ${appointments}" th:block
                         th:if="${appointment.dateTime.toLocalDate() == day}">
                        <div th:text="${doctor.firstName}"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said, calendar template looks good and I got events from database fine, I just want to add some thymeleaf conditions, again: If one some day I have more then 2 events, show two of them and other display after user click on see more button.

I tried like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Doctor Appointments</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/all-doctors-appointments.css">
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header-center">
    <h2 th:text="${monthYear}"></h2>
    <div class="button-container">
        <a class="btn btn-previous"
           th:href="@{/doctorAppointments/doctor-appointment-calendar(year=__${previousYear}__, month=__${previousMonth}__)}">Previous
            Month</a>
        <a class="btn btn-next"
           th:href="@{/doctorAppointments/doctor-appointment-calendar(year=__${nextYear}__, month=__${nextMonth}__)}">Next
            Month</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="calendar-header">
        <div th:each="dayName : ${dayNames}">
            <div th:text="${dayName}"></div>
        </div>
        <div th:each="week : ${calendarDays}" th:with="weekDates=${week}">
            <div th:each="day : ${weekDates}" class="calendar-day">
                <div class="day-number" th:text="${day.getDayOfMonth()}"></div>
                <div th:each="entry : ${doctorAppointmentsMap}"
                     th:with="doctor=${entry.key}, appointments=${entry.value}">
                    <div th:each="appointment, status : ${appointments}" th:block
                         th:if="${appointment.dateTime.toLocalDate() == day}">
                        <div class="appointment" th:text="${doctor.firstName}" th:class="${status.index >= 2 ? 'hidden' : ''}"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="see-more-btn" onclick="toggleVisibility(this)">See More</div>
                <div class="hidden-appointments">
                    <div th:each="entry : ${doctorAppointmentsMap}"
                         th:with="doctor=${entry.key}, appointments=${entry.value}">
                        <div th:each="appointment, status : ${appointments}" th:block
                             th:if="${appointment.dateTime.toLocalDate() == day}" th:class="${status.index < 2 ? 'hidden' : ''}">
                            <div class="appointment" th:text="${doctor.firstName}"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function toggleVisibility(button) {
        var hiddenAppointments = button.nextElementSibling;
        hiddenAppointments.classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But this produce see more for each day in month, also, for some day I need to click on see more to see events instead of displaying two events and if there is more display see more button.